# How do I get user input from separate classes

Tags: java

My goal is to get an amount for an item and a description of that item. I want to get 10 inputs and their values. I don't know how to store their info without asking for one then the other. I want to be able to ask for the user to input the item then price and then store each of those values.

I was trying to create an array of objects to enter and then was suggested to use arraylists which I kind of understand but don't know how to implement in this case.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Invoice {
    private ArrayList<Item> listOfItems;

    public Invoice() {
        listOfItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }


    public void addItem(Item item) {
        listOfItems.add(item);
    }

    public double calculateNetItemCost() {
        double netCost = 0;
        for(Item currentItem : listOfItems) {
        netCost += currentItem.getCost();
        }

        return netCost;
    }

    public double calculateTax(double taxRateAsADecimal) {
        return calculateNetItemCost() * taxRateAsADecimal;
    }

    public double calculateGST() {
        double GST = calculateNetItemCost() * 0.05;
        return GST;
    }

    public double calculatePST() {
        double PST = calculateNetItemCost() * 0.07;
        return PST;
    }

    public double calculateTotalCost() {
        double total = calculateGST() + calculatePST() + calculateNetItemCost();
        return total;
    }

}
```

```
public class Item {
    private double amount;
    private String description;

    public Item(String description, double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return description + ", $" + String.format("%.2f", amount);
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CustomerBuild {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Double> amount = new ArrayList<Double>();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;
        Item testItem = new Item("Apples", 4.00);

        System.out.println(testItem);

        Invoice testInvoice = new Invoice();
        testInvoice.addItem(testItem);


        double subTotal = testInvoice.calculateNetItemCost();
        System.out.println(subTotal);

        double GST = testInvoice.calculateGST();
        System.out.println("GST: " + GST);

        double PST = testInvoice.calculatePST();

        System.out.println("PST: " + PST);

        System.out.println("Total cost: " + testInvoice.calculateTotalCost());
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use class `Scanner` to get input from the user?

Comment: Yes, I would like to store 2 values that are taken from the user and then both amount and description stored into an object. The part where I am confused is getting the input to both ask for amount and description then save them as one before asking for the next. 

edit: this is as far as I got.

 System.out.println("Please enter a description");
  description = input.next();
  
  System.out.println("Please enter a price");
  amount = input.nextDouble();
  
  Item testItem2 = new Item(description, amount);

Comment: `System.out.println("Please enter a description"); description = input.next(); System.out.println("Please enter a price"); amount = input.nextDouble(); Item testItem2 = new Item(description, amount);` - and what is wrong with this code?

Comment: It works but feels like its clunky or too much. If I need to get 9 more values I will have to create 9 more objects. If I was able to make an array with  Item testItem2 = new Item(description, amount);  Then I would be able to loop both the user inputs with that right?

Comment: use loops, for Iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet is what are you looking for. Asking the user for input then initializing the object using the values

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter description(e.g.apple,banana,orange):");
    String description =input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Price(e.g.4.0,5.99):");
    Double price = scanner.nextDouble();
    Item testItem = new Item(description, price);
```

For Looping:

```
for(int i =1;i<10;i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter description(e.g.apple,banana,orange):");
        String description =input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Price(e.g.4.0,5.99):");
        Double price = scanner.nextDouble();
testInvoice.addItem(new Item(description, price));
}
```

Comment: So far this is similar to what I have done. But now with that done I am trying to loop it 10 times so I can input the items with their price. With this answer it works for 1 input and I'm struggling to figure out how to store those inputs into my Item object.

Comment: in this User has to enter values 10 times , the looping part one is creating a new object and adding to Invoice List at the same time

Comment: Reading the values 10 times through the user input
Creating the Object 10 times and adding to Invoice Object using testInvoice.addItem(new Item(description, price));

Comment: This worked perfectly, just what I was trying to figure out. Thank you very much!